# How do I get angular-resource to tell me which request is not matching object/array requirement?

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

Sometimes angular-resource expects an array but gets an object or vice-versa. Then I get a message like this:

```
Error: [$resource:badcfg] Error in resource configuration. Expected response to contain an object but got an array
```

If I have 3, 5 or even 10 Ajax requests going, I have no clue which one is making Angular complain.

How do I get it to tell me which URL or Resource is upsetting it?

Answer (score 1):

You have a url set up that is returning an array, look at the JSON in the response in the network tab and see which one has `[]` instead of `{}` (though you should know what your urls are returning).  Set the `isArray` property to true for that url in your resource.  [resource docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource):

```
{ 'get':    {method:'GET'},
  'save':   {method:'POST'},
  'query':  {method:'GET', isArray:true},
  'remove': {method:'DELETE'},
  'delete': {method:'DELETE'} };
```

Comment: yep, I know. But if I have 10 running, and all 10 return 200, it is hard to know which one Angular is complaining on. Sure, I could run through them one by one and modify, but I am looking for Angular to tell me, "resource User returned array instead of object" or "resource /api/user/123 returned array instead of object"

Comment: By the by, I have never liked the above assumption that `'get'` would have `isArray:false`, since I might want to do `GET /api/user/1,2.json` which would return an array. In my apps, I have a Resource override that allows for that, and then each specific one inherits from my Resource, rather than directly from $resource